# Creating shared key signature fails in CryptoJS

Tags: javascript, rest, azure, digital-signature, cryptojs

I need help with creating a shared key signature for Azure storage REST.

In chrome I can output the string I am signing:

```
PUT


11

text/plain;charset=UTF-8






x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob
x-ms-date:Wed, 09 Dec 2015 11:53:00 GMT
x-ms-version:2015-04-05
/myaccount/logs
```

Using Postman the server returned me the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
    <Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:6ca14d01-0001-00cb-5673-32e680000000
Time:2015-12-09T11:20:01.6093647Z</Message>
    <AuthenticationErrorDetail>The MAC signature found in the HTTP request 'O1Xwmg6TeU53qYoDiKQHgJZc+58uPaJPvotxXL116XQ=' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'PUT


11

text/plain;charset=UTF-8






x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob
x-ms-date:Wed, 09 Dec 2015 11:53:00 GMT
x-ms-version:2015-04-05
/myaccount/logs'.</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

As you can see both signed string are the same. I have checked, there is no difference between two texts.

This is the code the I execute to generate the signature:

```
var accessKeyBytes = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(base64EncodedSharedKey);
var encodedBits = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(stringToSign, accessKeyBytes);
var result = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(encodedBits);
return result;
```

where base64EncodedSharedKey is the primary key of the Azure storage.

Do you have any ideas? What could I be doing wrong? Should I backslash the \n when forming the JavaScript string to be signed?

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

The problem is that at the end of the string to be signed I had put a \n.

I should have not put the return carriage at the end of the string.